# Get results that have the same data in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get all the customer name where their preference MINPRICE and MAXPRICE is the same.

Here's my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE    CUSTOMER (
PHONE   VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
NAME    VARCHAR(25),
CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (PHONE),
);

CREATE TABLE    PREFERENCE (
PHONE   VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
ITEM        VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
MAXPRICE    NUMBER(8,2),
MINPRICE    NUMBER(8,2),
CONSTRAINT PREFERENCE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (PHONE, ITEM),
CONSTRAINT PREFERENCE_FKEY FOREIGN KEY (PHONE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (PHONE)
);
```

I think I need to do some compare between rows and rows? or create another views to compare? any easy way to do this?

its one to many. a customer can have multiple preferences so i need to query a list of customer that have the same minprice and maxprice. compare between rows minprice=minprice and maxprice=maxprice

Comment: (A phone number's not a good idea for a primary key/customer identifier. People change their phone numbers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self-join on `preference` would find rows with the same price preference, but a different phone number:

```
select  distinct c1.name
,       p1.minprice
,       p1.maxprice
from    preference p1
join    preference p2
on      p1.phone <> p2.phone
        and p1.minprice = p2.minprice
        and p1.maxprice = p2.maxprice
join    customer c1
on      c1.phone = p1.phone
join    customer c2
on      c2.phone = p2.phone
order by
        p1.minprice
,       p1.maxprice
,       c1.name
```

Comment: any better dynamic ways to do this? what if i have 3 name that have same value, 10 name that have same values, i dont want them to pair up two times between 3 names. i need a list of distinct names that has that same values

Comment: Modified the query so that you get a list of names with identical price points.  If you want a formatted list, have a look at [group_concat() in Oracle](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/05/group_concat-in-oracle-10g/).  It's probably better done client side.

Comment: You should use `<` rather than `<>`. Otherwise you get two results for each pair.

Comment: @Barmar: Note that it's listing one customer per row.  The query as now written actually need both pairs.

Comment: So you're telling all the customers that have another customer with the same preference, but not showing who they're paired up with?

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, see the OP's comment.  He is not looking for pairs but for the list of customers with the same preference.

Comment: i am getting the correct results now, but there is a duplicate results of the same name ,minprice and maxprice

Comment: That could happen if there's more than two users with the same preference.  One way to fix that is adding `distinct` (also done in answer.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that you have minprice and maxprice in your preference table. Is that a table that you update after each transaction, such that each customer only has 1 active preference record? I mean, it reads like a customer could pay two different prices for the same item, which seems odd.

Assuming customer and preference are 1:1

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customer c INNER JOIN preference p ON c.phone = p.phone
WHERE p.minprice = p.maxprice
```

However, if a customer can have multiple preferences and you are looking for minprice = maxprice for ALL item ... then you could do this

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT phone, MIN(minprice) as allMin, MAX(maxprice) as allMax
      FROM preference
      GROUP BY phone) p INNER JOIN customer c on p.phone = c.phone
WHERE allMin = allMax
```

Comment: sorry its one to many. a customer can have multiple preferences so i need to query a list of customer that have the same minprice and maxprice. compare between rows minprice=minprice and maxprice=maxprice

Answer (score 0):

This will show all the customer names that have the same price preferences.

```
SELECT minprice, maxprice, GROUP_CONCAT(name) names
FROM preference
JOIN customer USING (phone)
GROUP BY minprice, maxprice
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The `HAVING` clause prevents it showing preferences that have no duplicates. If you want to see those single-customer preferences, remove that line.

Comment: If Oracle supported `group_concat`, this would be the best soluiton :)

Comment: @Andomar Oops, forgot that he's using Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: @Andomar oracle supports `listagg` ;)